# ASP.NET Core (.net 4.7) project created with VS2017 does not work with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've created a new ASP.NET Core Project from scratch with the React Template of Visual Studio 2017 using the full .NET Framework instead of .NET Core as I need to use Entity Framework 6.

[image]

The project works without a problem in VS2017 and I can also build and run it with `dotnet run` and `dotnet build`.

But when I open the project in Visual Studio Code I always get the following error:

> `The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [Test]`

[image]

I've tried adding the `NETStandard.Library` to my project but the problem still exists.

These are all my referenced packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
```

I'm kind of clueless since googling for my error only brings up results of people having build problems, but my project builds without any issues.

Anything else I can try to get this working?

**EDIT:** My only installed extension is the c# extension provided by Microsoft if that makes any difference.

Comment: From my understanding Visual Studio Code does not support the .net framework, only the core framework.

Comment: "The project works without a problem in VS2017".  Why don't you use VS2017 then?  With all due respect, it kind of seems like you are trying to get some help solving a problem that isn't really there.

Comment: @Seano666 Because VS Code is much more lightweight and has better performance when developing on a Notebook. Besides writing JavaScript just "feels" more pleasant with VS Code, even if I can't really put my finger on it why, as this is probably more subjective.

Comment: @ChrisBartlett You can use c# console applications targeting the full framework without a problem in VS Code, so this seems to be specific to the ASP.NET Core and full framework combination.